# Quadrilaterals containing a square number of lattice points

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge

I am working on [Project Euler problem 504](https://projecteuler.net/problem=504), which states:

> Let \$ABCD\$ be a quadrilateral whose vertices are lattice points lying on the coordinate axes as follows:
>
> \$A(a, 0), B(0, b), C(−c, 0), D(0, −d)\$ where \$1 ≤ a, b, c, d ≤ m\$ and \$a, b, c, d, m\$ are integers.
>
> It can be shown that for \$m = 4\$ there are exactly 256 valid ways to construct \$ABCD\$. Of these 256 quadrilaterals, 42 of them *strictly* contain a square number of lattice points.
>
> How many quadrilaterals \$ABCD\$ strictly contain a square number of lattice points for \$m = 100\$?

My code is working fine, but the issue is optimization. I am already using memoization.

```
from fractions import gcd
from math import fabs
def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners)
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

def isSquare(n):
    sqrt = n ** 0.5
    if sqrt == int(sqrt):
        return True
    return False

memo = {}
def lattice(p1, p2):
    t = (fabs(p2[0] - p1[0]), fabs(p2[1] - p1[1]))
    g = gcd(t[0], t[1]) + 1
    if not t in memo:
        memo[t] = g
    return memo[t]


def boundary(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return (lattice(p1, p2) + lattice(p2, p3) + lattice(p3, p4) + lattice(p4, p1) - 4)

def interior(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    corners = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
    A = PolygonArea(corners)
    B = boundary(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    I = A - B/2 + 1
    return I

squares = set([x**2 for x in xrange(1000)])
count = 0
for a in xrange(1, 101):
    for b in xrange(1, 101):
        for c in xrange(1, 101):
            for d in xrange(1, 101):
                I = interior((a, 0),(0, b),(-1*c, 0),(0, -1*d))
                if I in squares:
                    count += 1
print count
```

Comment: Do you have to deal with decimal numbers or are only whole integer numbers relevant?

Comment: You memorize but you don't make use of your memorization?

Comment: @Gareth: You added a link, but that does not point to Project Euler.

Comment: @MartinR: Sorry about that.

Comment: @Simon Only Integers.

Comment: You could optimize by avoiding the integer -> float conversions. Simply by // divide. If possible wouldn't claim to understand the solution.

You could use abs() only and not use fabs(), if fabs is slower in 2.7, I believe it is, else you could use only fabs, the implementations differ. Use tuple instead of lists. These tips are minor, is there some condition you are missing,

Comment: Now you are checking 100million permutations, right?

Comment: Yep. I ran the code with the improvements, it took 3 minutes for 100 million. @Simon

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It isn't C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. There are no docstrings. What do all these functions do? How do I call them? What do they return?
2. The code is not portable to Python 3 because it uses `xrange` and the `print` statement.
3. The function `isSquare` is not used and could be removed.
4. The function `lattice` does not actually make use of the memoization (it doesn't look at the dictionary `memo` until it has already computed the result).
5. There's no need to use [`math.fabs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fabs) as the vertices are all at integer points. You could use [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) instead.
6. The program is hard to test because it has code that runs at the top level. This means that you can't run it from the interactive interpreter, or using `timeit`. It would be better to organize the code into functions to make it easier to test.
7. It's inconsistent for the function `PolygonArea` to have a name using CamelCase but other functions (`lattice`, `boundary`, `interior`) to have names using lower case.
8. The nested loops can be replaced by a single loop using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).
9. In order to work on the performance, it would be handy if the parameter \$m=100\$ were not hard-coded. We'd like to be able to run the code with smaller values of \$m\$ and see how the runtime behaves.

#### 2. Revised code

```
from fractions import gcd
from itertools import product

def polygon_area(corners):
    """Return the area of the polygon with the given vertices."""
    n = len(corners)
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

_memo = {}
def lattice(p1, p2):
    """Return the number of lattice points on the line from p1 to p2."""
    t = abs(p2[0] - p1[0]), abs(p2[1] - p1[1])
    if t not in _memo:
        g = gcd(t[0], t[1]) + 1
        _memo[t] = g
    return _memo[t]

def boundary(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    """Return the number of lattice points on the boundary of the
    quadrilateral with vertices p1, p2, p3, p4.

    """
    return lattice(p1, p2) + lattice(p2, p3) + lattice(p3, p4) + lattice(p4, p1) - 4

def interior(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    """Return the number of lattice points in the interior of the
    quadrilateral with vertices p1, p2, p3, p4.

    """
    corners = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
    A = polygon_area(corners)
    B = boundary(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    I = A - B/2 + 1
    return I

def problem504(m=100):
    """Return the number of quadrilaterals with vertices lying at lattice
    points on the coordinate axes, no more than m units from the
    origin, whose interior contains a square number of lattice points.

    """
    squares = set(i ** 2 for i in range(2 * m))
    count = 0
    for a, b, c, d in product(range(1, m + 1), repeat=4):
        I = interior((a, 0), (0, b), (-c, 0), (0, -d))
        if I in squares:
            count += 1
    return count
```

#### 3. Measurement

We expect the runtime to be proportional to \$m^4\$, so let's see how this performs on smaller values of \$m\$ and then fit a curve to figure out the projected runtime for \$m = 100\$. Note that because `lattice` is memoized, we have to be careful to reset the memoization each time.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> _memo={}; timeit(lambda:problem504(10), number=1)
0.10902838699985296
>>> _memo={}; timeit(lambda:problem504(20), number=1)
1.7153344419784844
>>> _memo={}; timeit(lambda:problem504(30), number=1)
8.644499261979945
>>> _memo={}; timeit(lambda:problem504(40), number=1)
28.569149894057773
```

Let's fit these results to the equation \$t = am^4\$:

[image]

Gnuplot finds \$a = 1.11 × 10^{-5}\$, so we predict that when \$m=100\$, the runtime will be about 1110 seconds (about 19 minutes).

#### 4. Performance improvement

The code here is general-purpose — for example `polygon_area` computes the area of *any* polygon. But in this problem we don't need the general case — we only have *quadrilaterals* whose vertices are at *lattice points* on the *coordinate axes*. So the obvious thing to do is to reduce the amount of work by only computing the bare minimum, and reusing as many results as we can.

The key observation is that we can compute the number of interior points in the quadrilateral from the number of interior points in the four right-angled triangles in the four quadrants, like this:

[image]

If I write \$T(a, b)\$ for the number of interior points in the triangle with vertices \$(0, 0)\$, \$(a, 0)\$ and \$(0, b)\$, then this diagram shows that the value we want is $$Q(a, b, c, d) = T(a, b) + T(b, c) + T(c, d) + T(d, a) + a + b + c + d - 3.$$ The value of \$T(a, b)\$ can be computed in various ways, for example using [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem). I like to use this diagram:

[image]

in which there are \$(a - 1)(b - 1)\$ dots altogether, of which \$\gcd(a, b) - 1\$ lie exactly on the hypotenuse (the grey dot), and the remainder divide into two equal halves (the blue and red dots), so $$T(a, b) = {(a - 1)(b - 1) - \gcd(a, b) + 1 \over 2}.$$ In this example, \$a=10\$ and \$b=12\$ so \$\gcd(a, b) = 2\$ and \$T(a, b) = 49\$.

There are now some micro-optimizations we can make:

1. Let \$U(a, b) = T(a, b) + a\$. Then $$Q(a, b, c, d) = U(a, b) + U(b, c) + U(c, d) + U(d, a) - 3$$ which avoids four additions.
2. Instead of creating a set of squares, create a set of squares plus 3. Then we can test \$U(a, b) + U(b, c) + U(c, d) + U(d, a)\$ to see if it is a square plus 3. This saves a subtraction.
3. Instead of maintaining a set of squares plus 3, create a list whose \$i\$th entry is `True` if \$i\$ is a square plus 3, and `False` otherwise. Fetching a list entry is faster than determining if an item is in a set.

That results in the following code:

```
def problem504a(m=100):
    """Return the number of quadrilaterals with vertices lying at lattice
    points on the coordinate axes, no more than m units from the
    origin, whose interior contains a square number of lattice points.

    """
    square_plus_three = [False] * (4 * m * m + 3)
    for i in range(2 * m):
        square_plus_three[i * i + 3] = True
    R = range(m + 1)
    U = [[((a - 1) * (b - 1) - gcd(a, b) + 1) // 2 + a for a in R] for b in R]
    count = 0
    for a, b, c, d in product(range(1, m + 1), repeat=4):
        if square_plus_three[U[a][b] + U[b][c] + U[c][d] + U[d][a]]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

After all those micro-optimizations, we had better check that we haven't made a mistake. So let's test the new code against the old code:

```
>>> all(problem504(i) == problem504a(i) for i in range(20))
True
```

And see what the performance is like:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:problem504a(10), number=1)
0.007875622948631644
>>> timeit(lambda:problem504a(20), number=1)
0.09821957419626415
>>> timeit(lambda:problem504a(30), number=1)
0.49982553208246827
>>> timeit(lambda:problem504a(40), number=1)
1.6008274049963802
>>> timeit(lambda:problem504a(50), number=1)
4.018431055126712
```

The runtime is still \$Θ(m^4)\$ so here's the best fit to \$t = am^4\$ as before:

[image]

Gnuplot finds \$a = 6.4 × 10^{-7}\$ and so we predict that when \$m=100\$, the runtime will be about 64 seconds. In practice it takes a little longer than that:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:problem504a(100), number=1)
69.0101949761156
```

Answer (score 0):

### memonization

```
def lattice(p1, p2):
    pair = (p1, p2)
    if pair in memo:
        return memo[pair]
    t1, t2 = fabs(p2[0] - p1[0]), fabs(p2[1] - p1[1])
    g = gcd(t1, t2) + 1
    memo[pair] = g
    return g
```

### main loop

Instead of

```
count = 0
for a in xrange(1, 101):
    for b in xrange(1, 101):
        for c in xrange(1, 101):
            for d in xrange(1, 101):
                I = interior((a, 0),(0, b),(-1*c, 0),(0, -1*d))
                if I in squares:
                    count += 1
```

use `itertools`

```
import itertools
count = sum(1 for a, b, c, d in itertools.product(range(1, 101), repeat=4)
            if interior((a, 0),(0, b),(-c, 0),(0, -d)) in squares)
```

### PolygonArea

Your polygon always have 4 corners. You don't need to calculate length every time.

```
def SquareArea(corners):
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(4):
        j = (i + 1) % 4
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area
```

Comment: Is this an answer to to optimization question?

Comment: @Tomasz Jakub Rup Isn't it Memoization and not memonization?